# Why do the following have the same value: the pointer to an array, the dereferenced pointer to the array?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

For instance,

```
int array[5] = {1}: // array of 5 integers
int (*ptr)[5] = &array; // pointer to an array of 5 integers
```

The following have the same value:

```
*ptr;
ptr;
```

If I were to call `printf("%p, %p", *ptr, ptr);` both outputs would be exactly the same.  Why is this?

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @inetknght: It is declared and initialized in the second line of code.

Comment: This question has been asked many times.  In both C and C++, array names "decay" to pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c.  This line `int (*ptr)[5] = &array` both declares and initializes the variable "ptr".

Comment: Note, however, that `*ptr + 1` and `ptr + 1` have different values because the types are different.

Comment: The possible duplicate question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957) does not mention `&array`, and the top answer does not discuss `&array`, which makes it not a duplicate.  Related, certainly; duplicate, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this statement

```
int (*ptr)[5] = &array;
```

pointer ptr is initialized by the address of the array. The address of the array is the address of its first element that is of the first row.

Expression

```
*ptr;
```

gives you reference to this first element that is to the one-dimensional array - the first row or more precisely to the original array..

In turn in expressions arrays are converted to pointers to their first elements and `*ptr` that is equivalent to expression `array` is converted to rvalue of type pointer that points to the first element of array `*ptr`.:)
That is expression `*ptr` will have type `int *`
The address of the first row and the address of the first element of the first row is the same.
Now you have two pointers, `ptr` and `*ptr` the first one has type `int ( * )[5]` while the second one has type `int *` but the both have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the memory layout of a 1D array such as

```
int array[5];
```

it will make sense.

```
        array
          |
          V 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

  array[0]
  |
  V 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

Address of array
|
V 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

Address of array[0]
|
V 
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

i.e. `&array == &array[0] == array decayed to a pointer`

With a pointer declared as:

```
int (*ptr)[5] = &array;

ptr == &array
*ptr == array decayed to a pointer == &array[0] == &array
```

That's why you see the same value printed when you use:

```
printf("%p, %p", *ptr, ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `printf` is a variadic function, the [ellipsis conversion sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) are applied to the arguments. In particular, arrays are [decayed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array_to_pointer_decay) to a pointer of the underlying type : IOW, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. Thus, when you call `printf("%p, %p", *ptr, ptr);`, `*ptr`, which is of type `int[5]` is converted to an `int*` with value `&array[0]`.